# How can I create a navigation link that creates a new object then passes that object to the destination?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am trying to create a `navigationDestination` that accepts an object that has just been created and also support objects that already exist in my array.

Here is my code:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedResults(Meal.self) var meals
    @State private var mealCreated = false
    @State private var selectedMeal: Meal?
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                let columns = [GridItem(),GridItem(),GridItem()]
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
                    
                    ZStack {
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 8)
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        selectedMeal = createNewMeal()
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(meals) { meal in
                        MealCell(meal: meal)
                            .padding()
                            .contextMenu {
                                Button(role: .destructive) {
                                    $meals.remove(meal)
                                } label: {
                                    Text("Delete")
                                }
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedMeal = meal
                            }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: $selectedMeal) { meal in
                MealView(meal: meal)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Meals")
        }
    }
    func createNewMeal() -> Meal {
        let meal = Meal()
        $meals.append(meal)
        return meal
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doen’t work?

Comment: navigationDestination(for: can only accept an object that already exists, I was trying to bind this with a variable - but it doesn't work like that

Comment: navigationDestination accept a type not a var.